# Persisting data in iOS documents directory

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an app that saves a recorded video to the documents directory, as well as a `Post` object, and populates a collection view from the `Post` object. However upon restarting the app, the collection view is empty, so the videos being saved to the docs directory is not persisting (at least I think that's the problem).

This is the function that saves the video:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
        var uniqueVideoID = ""
        var videoURL:NSURL? = NSURL()
        var uniqueID = ""

        uniqueID = NSUUID().uuidString

        // Get the path as URL and store the data in myVideoVarData
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL as NSURL?
        let myVideoVarData = try! Data(contentsOf: videoURL! as URL)

        // Write data to temp diroctory
        let tempPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let tempDocumentsDirectory: AnyObject = tempPath[0] as AnyObject
        uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "TEMPVIDEO.MOV"
        let tempDataPath = tempDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
        try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath), options: [])

        // Get the time value of the video
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fileURL)
        let duration : CMTime = asset.duration

        // Remove the data from the temp Document Diroctory.
        do{
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: tempDataPath)
        } catch {
            //Do nothing
        }

        // Check to see if video is under the 18500 (:30 seconds)
        if duration.value <= 18500 {

            // Write the data to the Document Directory
            let docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
            let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = docPaths[0] as AnyObject
            uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "VIDEO.MOV"
            let docDataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
            try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), options: [])
            print("docDataPath under picker ",docDataPath)
            print("Video saved to documents directory")

            //Create a thumbnail image from the video
            let assetImageGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImageGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)
            if let videoImage = try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) {
                //Add thumbnail & video path to Post object
                let video = Post(pathToVideo: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), thumbnail: UIImage(cgImage: videoImage))
                posts.append(video)
                print("Video saved to Post object")
            }
        }else{
            print("Video not saved")
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, this is where the video path and thumbnail are added to my object:

```
            //Add thumbnail & video path to Post object
            if let videoImage = try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) {
                let video = Post(pathToVideo: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), thumbnail: UIImage(cgImage: videoImage))
                posts.append(video)
```

So I do give it the path to the video in the documents directory; how can I ensure that the data persists there?

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To verify if the videos are being saved on the device, connect the device to Xcode and navigate to Window->Devices in Xcode. Then select your device on the left and find your app in the Installed Apps list. Select your app and click on the gear icon at the bottom of the list and press 'Show Containter'. Wait for a few seconds and you should see all the folders in your app.

Secondly, not sure why you are writing the video and deleting it and writing it back again and also why use 'try?' instead of actually catching any exceptions thrown during the file write?

Comment: It looks like the videos are definitely getting saved - I posted a screenshot in my edit.

Comment: So I would think that the following line might be throwing the exception.
`try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage`

Comment: Also, did you try stepping through the code in debugger?

Comment: Is there a better way of handling that line? And I haven't tried stepping through the code for this particular issue although to be honest I wouldn't know what red flags to look for here.

Comment: The if/let statement and `try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage` is doing its job of getting the thumbnail, because it does show up in my collection view, along with the video path (tapping on the CV cell plays the video). It's just that the data isn't persisting between runs of the app.

Comment: Oh missed the part about data missing after restarting the app. So where do you repopulate your posts array? The code above is only triggered when the user dismisses the imageViewPicker. You would need to go through the documents directory and populate your posts array in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, etc.

Comment: Bare with me because I'm not very experienced, but I'm not sure what you mean by "repopulate" the array.. I was under the impression that upon recording a video and dismissing the picker, that video and thumbnail were saved to the docs directory and the post object. Then I populate my collection view from the object (which holds the file path to the video)

Comment: Yes but when you restart the app, the post object and array are no longer in memory so there is nothing to populate the collection view from. The videos in the document folder do persist between app launches, therefore on app restart you would need to go through the documents folder and re-create the Post objects and tell the collection view to `reloadData`.

Comment: Ok gotcha. But the thumbnail and video path are generated when the video is taken, in `didFinishPickingMedia`, in `RecordVideoViewController`, so I don't know how to re-populate the post object in `viewDidAppear` in the feed controller. Can you post an example in your answer?

Comment: Also I'm guessing I'll have to save the thumbnail to the documents directory also? Right now the thumbnail is only saved to the post object. I'm not sure how to do that because it looks like I can only write URLs (`try? myVideoVarData.write(to: <#T##URL#>)`)

Comment: You could potentially save the thumbnails in a separate directory as well and use the uniqueID in the filename. Then when you enumerate through your video files, you could look up the thumbnail file using the uniqueID in the thumbnail directory. Unfortunately without knowing the context of your app it's hard to provide sample code and might also be non-trivial.